# Buffered Reader Change

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Hi I want to replace the BufferedReader in the piece of code with scanner?? I wrote this code but then realized that we're not allowed use bufferedreader. But Havent a clue how to even go about,

```
 public static void Option1Method() throws IOException 
{
 FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("wordlist.txt", true);
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
 String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word");

 out.println(word);
 out.close();

 aFileWriter.close();

 String inputFile = "wordlist.txt";
 String outputFile = "wordlist.txt";
 FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
 String inputLine;
 List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
 while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lineList.add(inputLine);
  }
 fileReader.close();

 Collections.sort(lineList);

 FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
 PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
 for (String outputLine : lineList) {
     out1.println(outputLine);
 }
 out1.flush();
 out1.close();
 fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of Scanner? What don't you understand?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Javadoc for the `Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)? It provides some examples how you can use it.

Comment: So am i just replacing BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader); with Scanner s = new Scanner(FileReader);
     s.findInLine??

Comment: Read the documentation and try things. If it doesn't work at the first time, fix the bugs until it works. It's not like if you were building a house. A program can be fixed and rewritten many times, without any consequence. Staring at the screen and wandering if something will work is not the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the definitions for [`hasNextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) and [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) in the `Scanner` class.

Although `new Scanner(fileReader)` works, you could rather pass the file name directly into the `Scanner`'s constructor.